# Guest menu not appearing in Joomla

Tags: html, joomla, content-management-system

Following the example in [Joomla Docs](http://docs.joomla.org/Access_Control_List/2.5/Tutorial#Allowing_Guest-Only_Access_to_Menu_Items_and_Modules) I made a guest-only menu item for people who are not logged into the intranet I'm working on to be able to see a few pages. However no matter what I change or do, the menu item does not appear on the homepage when logged out, even when set to 'Public'.

It appears on the menu when logged in if set to any viewing group **apart** from 'Guest'.

Racking my brain trying to figure this one out but can't get a handle on it. Is there a setting or something I could have checked that would be messing this all up?

I could theorize that there's something preventing **any** menu items displaying on my front page. Since Guest items function as required when logged in (ie. by not appearing), and even Public items won't appear when logged out. Can't point to what could cause that though.

Site is here: http://avantgardeinternational.eu/ but that may be of dubious use since everything but the homepage is private.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course, after a couple of days lost with this one, I figured it out myself half an hour after I post the question.

It seems that I had set the **module** for the main menu to the 'registered' usergroup some time ago, when I had not wanted any menu items on the front page, and so even though the menu was public, the module was not loading to show the links. Setting the module to public access solved the issue.